# Egit ssh changes push & pull

Tags: git, ubuntu, egit

In my office Eclipse is being used popularly and I have newly installed `GIT` and `Egit` plugin for Eclipse.
I'm not CVCS or DVCS user and I'm asked to install and configure Egit.
I could able to clone a remote projects **Graphically** with Egit between Ubuntu desktop systems.
Where I'm failing to understand is, when ever I create any folder/file under the project or update the project and after pulling (`R.C on project>Team>Pull`) or pushing (`R.C on project>Team>Remote>Push`) it's says `Up-to-date`, but I could not see any newly created folders/files or updated files on the another computer.

What's the proper way of doing push and pull after cloning the repo with Egit?
I'm trying in this way:

- Updated a project on a computer
- Did R.C on project`>Team>Add` and `Team>Commit`
- Went to Remote computer and did R.C on project>`Team>Pull` and got the prompt Up-to-date
- I did `Team>Add` and `Team>Commit` on this remote computer but I didn't see the changes which is made on the source computer.

Please don't scold me as I've no much knowledge.
How do I do proper push and pull between two computers with Egit?.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(I would never scold you ;) )</sup>

Just to be sure, you did `Team>Add` and `Team>Commit` on the source computer?
Because unless you commit changes on the source computer, you won't be able to R.C. ("Remote Control", I suppose?) on the remote computer and `Team>Pull` there: it would pull nothing from the source computer repo.

Comment: It's nice to see you again. I really liked `(I would never scold you ;) )`. Oh is it, I did `Add` and `commit` on the source computer. I'll check this again and let you know

Comment: I'm having the same problem while Team>Add as he has posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451773/eclipse-git-cant-add-files-to-my-repository

Comment: @user465465: what exact version of Eclipse are you using? With what JDK? And what eclipse.ini?

Comment: Oh sorry for late response. 2day I was busy upgrading ubuntu karmic. As far as I know I installed Eclipse Galileo on all the systems and I don't know about eclipse.ini, I"ll check and tell you!

Comment: And the way of installation is also not from ubuntu apt repository. Developers ask me to do manual install like, extract galileo zip and move it under /usr/share/, give full permissions and  to add eclipse as new item in the `System>Preferences>Main Menu` to appear eclipse in `Application>Programming>Eclipse`

Comment: @user465465: Galileo? Why not Helios: 3.6.2 (released yesterday)

Comment: Ok, it's better asking all the developers to change their Eclipse version to Helios.

Comment: I checked it installing Helios on two computers and I'v having the same problem. Some where I'm doing wrong. Instead links if you could give some practical steps to clone, and to fetch and pull the updates with egit, I could help find out where I'm doing wrong. Just a small example of it.

Comment: Again I could see some improvement. I could see the changes made on one computer to another. But how to see newly created files/directories of remote computer and add to my existing project

Comment: @user465465: newly created files/directory need to be committed first on one side, then pulled from the other side. One way I like to import a Git repo into EGit, is first to make it work through command lines, and then import it in the Eclipse workspace.